# How to save image while keeping dimensions and pixels same?

Tags: matlab

I have to save the image. But when I try and keep the dimensions same, pixel values change. Is there any way to keep both intact.

```
C=imread('download.jpg');   



 C=rgb2gray(C);

%convert to DCT
 [r1 c1]=size(C);
  CDCT=floor(dct2(C)); 
  dct=floor(dct2(C));
  [r c]= size(dCipherText);
  bye=c; %lenght of message bits
  for i=r1:r1

for j=c1:-1:c1-28


 .....%some operation on CDCT

  end

end 
imshow(idct2(CDCT),[0 255])
i=idct2(CDCT);

 set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 c1 r1])
print -djpeg fa.jpg -r1
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use print to save the picture.
Use:

```
imwrite(i,'downdload_dct.jpg')
```

`print` will use the paper dimensions etc defined on your figure, rather than the image data itself. `imwrite` uses the data in `i`. You don't need `imshow` if you just want to re-save the image.

--
Update - sorry I see now that when you mean 'scaling', you don't mean the scaling of the picture but of the pixel values, and converting back from scalars to a colour. `imshow` only "scales" things on the screen, not in your actual data. So you will need to do that manually / numerically. Something like this would work, assuming `i` is real.

```
% ensure i ranges from 1 to 255 
i = 1 + 254*(i-min(i(:))*(max(i(:))-min(i(:))) ;
% convert indices to RGB colour values (m x n x 3 array)
i = ind2rgb(i,jet(256));
```

not tested!

Comment: And don't use `.jpg`. Use a lossless format like `.png`.

Comment: If I don't do imshow before that then how do I scale the image. Because image is basically inverse of DCT and when it is saved as it is, the resultant image is different

Comment: @user3102085 What isn't working? Try `imwrite(uint8(idct2(CDCT)), 'download_dct.png')`. This relies on `uint8` to perform the scaling

Comment: OK I think I understand your question - I've updated the answer.